# How to create an archive file with Maven plugin

Tags: maven, archive

Using Maven I would like to create an archive file with a custom extension (.bar). I have to include a class file and an XML file in it.

I tried the below but could not complete it.

```
     <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>

                <execution>
                   <id>compile</id>
                   <phase>compile</phase>
                   <configuration>
                       <target>
                            <echo message="generating document workflow .bar file" />
                           **I need to copy a .class file and an xml file then build the .bar file.**                                

                           <!-- Create a bar file. -->
                           <zip basedir="${project.build.outputDirectory}" destfile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/document-workflow.bar" />
                      </target>
                   </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Could you please guide me?

I have another requirement. Basically, the class file that I want to copy to jar should be in the root and not in the package structure.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will solve your problem:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>bar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <echo message="generating document workflow .bar file" />
                    <!-- flatten files -->
                    <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/flattened_classes" flatten="true">
                        <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
                            <include name="**/*.class"/>
                        </fileset>
                    </copy>
                    <!-- Create a bar file. -->
                    <zip  destfile="${project.build.directory}/document-workflow.bar" >
                        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/flattened_classes">
                            <include name="**/*.class"/>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}">
                            <include name="yourfile.xml"/>
                        </fileset>
                    </zip>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```